# spawning thread using static function using TBB in C++

Tags: c++, tbb

I want to use TBB threads in C++ and want to use "tbb_thread" API.

for example i have static function in class as below

```
template < typename threadFuncParamT >
class ThreadWrapper
{
public:
    static int ThreadRoutineFunction(void* pParam);
};
```

I want to use tbb_thread API to spawn a thread with "ThreadRoutineFunction" which is defined above class. How can i achieve this using tbb_thread API. please note that i have to pass pointer to the thread routine function. Can any one give me simple example how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your question is really "how do I get a pointer to a `static` member function?"

C++ doesn't officially have a way to do that.  However, according to the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2) (the Note in question 2), "pointers-to-`static`-member-functions are *usually* type-compatible with regular pointers-to-functions."

Your options are:

1. Use a regular pointer to function, point it at your `static` member function, see if your compiler complains:

   ```
   int (*ptrFunction)(void*) = ThreadWrapper<Foo>::ThreadRoutineFunction;
   ```
2. Do what the FAQ suggests, and declare your function `extern "C"` as well as `static` (you'll also have to declare the pointer to the function as `extern "C"`, and you won't be able to overload the function):

   ```
   template <typename T> class ThreadWrapper {
       public:
       extern "C" static int ThreadRoutineFunction(void* param);
   };

   extern "C" int(*ptrCFunction)(void*) = ThreadWrapper<Foo>::ThreadRoutineFunction;
   ```
3. Create an additional function that does nothing but call the `static` member function:

   ```
   template <typename T> int ThreadWrapperHelper(void* param)
   {
       return ThreadWrapper<T>::ThreadRoutineFunction(param);
   }

   int (*ptrFunction)(void*) = ThreadWrapperHelper<Foo>;
   ```

Comment: In fact, the C++ standard (both 2003 and 2011 editions) says in a footnote to 5.2.2 that "A static member function is an ordinary function". Also in a couple of other places (e.g. 3.9.2) pointers to static members said to be equivalent to regular pointers. Thus I think the option (1) in your answer should work with any standard-compliant compiler. The cited FAQ suggests to use `extern "C"` to avoid calling convention issues when a pointer to a C++ function is passed to call from a C library routine; this advice also applies to non-member functions. Overall, a good and comprehensive answer; +1.